# how to draw text which prompt the user in CGContext

Tags: ios, text, draw, cgcontext

I want to draw text in CGContext. I draw text when I write it from string. But I want to prompt the user this text. How can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using UIAlertView:

```
UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
alert.message = @"Enter new string";
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
UITextField* textField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
textField.placeholder = @"text";

[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];
alert.cancelButtonIndex = 0;
alert.delegate = self;
[alert show];
```

Handle the 'OK' button press:

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (alertView.cancelButtonIndex != buttonIndex) {
        NSString* text = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text;
        [self.myView setString:text];


    }
}
```

The method `setString:` of your custom view should set its NSString ivar and call `[self setNeedsDisplay]` or - if you know the frame where the string is drawn - better call `[self setNeedsDisplayInRect:stringFrame]`.